# Add text label to drawn shape

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm following along with this tutorial for drawing squares where-ever there is a gesture recognized touch on the screen in iOS.

https://www.weheartswift.com/bezier-paths-gesture-recognizers/

I am now wanting to extend the functionality and want to add text labels to my newly drawn shapes indicating their coordinates.

So touching the screen would draw a rectangle, which moves with the pan gesture (so far so good) but I would also like it to show numbers indicating the coordinates.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

```
class CircularKeyView: UIView {

    // a lot of this code came from https://www.weheartswift.com/bezier-paths-gesture-recognizers/
    //all thanks goes to we<3swift

    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0
    let size: CGFloat = 44.0

    init(origin: CGPoint) {

        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size, size))
        self.center = origin
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        initGestureRecognizers() //start up all the gesture recognizers
    }
    func initGestureRecognizers() {
        let panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didPan:")
        addGestureRecognizer(panGR)

    }

    //PAN IT LIKE u FRYIN.
    func didPan(panGR: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        self.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(self)

        var translation = panGR.translationInView(self)

        self.center.x += translation.x
        self.center.y += translation.y


        panGR.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)
    }


    // We need to implement init(coder) to avoid compilation errors
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 7)

        //draws awesome curvy rectangle
        UIColor.darkGrayColor().setFill()
        path.fill()

        //draws outline
        path.lineWidth = self.lineWidth 
        UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
        path.stroke()

        //////
        //probably where I should draw the text label on this thing,
        //although it needs to update when the thingy moves. 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want Tap Gestures, then why are you using pan gesture?

Comment: @ShubhamOjha ideally the coordinate label/text will update on a movement of the thingies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `drawRect` implementation you can draw the coordinates of the view with something like:

```
("\(frame.origin.x), \(frame.origin.y)" as NSString).drawAtPoint(.zero, withAttributes: [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()
    ])
```

Which simply creates a string of the coordinates, casts it to an `NSString` and then calls the `drawAtPoint` method to draw it in the view's context.

You can of course change `.zero` to any `CGPoint` depending on where you want to draw the string and can edit the attributes as desired.

To make sure that this gets updated when the user pans around you will want to also add:

```
self.setNeedsDisplay()
```

to the bottom of your `didPan` method.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this helps tremendously, thank you.  I was about to ask how to update it on pan and saw you had pre-emotively answered! :)